# To which device should the fpv camera be connected: flight controller or video transmitter?

Tags: flight-controller, video-transmitters, fpv-cameras

I have FC Matek F405-WMN and 5.8GHz transmitter TBS UNIFY PRO32 HV. The F405 wiring diagram (http://www.mateksys.com/?portfolio=f405-wmn#tab-id-4) shows that two cameras can be connected to it. But I also see camera pins on the trasmitter. So, to which device should I connect camera (CADDX ANT 1200TVL)?

Also, I see on wiring diagram how to connect control RX module (I'm using crossfire nano rx), but I don't see here the video tx module. Should I use any free appropriate pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Originally the camera's video output was sent directly to the VTX. However it is now common for it to be connected to the flight controller, which adds the on-screen-display (OSD) data, and then to the VTX. The flight controller has two pads for video-in (C1 and C2) and a video-out pad for the VTX (labelled VTX).

Note that the camera and VTX may not use the same voltage. You should look up the voltage they require, and connect to the relevant pad (either 5v or VBat). The 0v wires will all be common, so any 'ground' pad will work.

The Tx/Rx pins on the VTX are for 'smart audio', which is nothing to do with audio, but allows the flight controller to communicate digitally with the VTX. That allows you to change VTX settings, such as channel. Connect these to any spare UART Tx/Rx pads on the flight controller. Note that the Tx output on one device connects to the Rx input on the other. This is entirely optional. It will still send video without it.

[image: Matek F405-WMN FC layout]
[image: TBS UNIFY PRO32 HV layout]

Comment: Does OSD pin from the camera also need to be connected to flight controller?

Comment: I've not heard of an OSD pin on a camera, and don't know what it would do. You'd have to check the documentation for the camera. Some cameras have their own OSD, but generally you want to use the one generated by the flight controller because it has a lot more information.